# Random forest visualization

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree, feature-selection

For a dataset I ran a random forest model with sikit learn. When I checked important variables from RF , I was unable to understand the reason for choosing that variable as important.  In my understanding There would be rules for the tree built by RF. Is there a way to visualize the trees and understand the rules. Or how can I know the reason on choosing that variable as important by RF

Comment: See the [22 existing questions on *random forest visualization*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=visualize+random+forest+tree+is%3Aquestion). Also, look at a table or plot of ***variable importance***, this tells you which variables were chosen by the RF. Tell us which question most closely matches, so we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*the reason*"? What would be a satisfactory explanation (beyond that the algorithm has tried each variable in many splits, and has found some of them important and informative ans some others not)?